# Query several 'starts with' values in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I was trying to query values in a table where they started with 'a', 'b' or 'c'.  I know in MS SQL you can make a [charlist] to do this:

( LIKE '[abc]%' )

I was wondering what the correct syntax was in other databases such as Oracle or mySQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can use Regular Expressions

```
where some_column REGEXP '[abc].*'
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL follows the same syntax. Use % to wildcard, or ? single characters:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` LIKE 'a%' OR `column` LIKE 'b%'...
```

Alternatively, You can use REGEXP in MySQL, but it will cause performance hits as you are unable to use indexes in order to query data.

For the `SELECT LIKE 'a%'` query it will be able to use the index to lookup all items starting with A, and return them efficiently. Using REGEXP will cause a row scan for each item, and performance will be greatly impacted.

Answer (score 0):

**In Oracle,**
you can use the LIKE operator to match patterns. The syntax is similar to MySql:

```
WHERE column_name LIKE 'a%' OR column_name LIKE 'b%' OR column_name LIKE 'c%'
```

you can use the regular expression(REGEXP_LIKE) functions in Oracle.

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(your_column_name, '^[abc]')
```